# Format json array in required format

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

this is the json format

```
[ { baseurl: 'http://localhost:5051/springbootdemo/getServerData',
    server: '1' },
  { baseurl: 'http://localhost:5052/springbootdemo/getServerData',
    server: '1' },
  { baseurl: 'http://localhost:5053/springbootdemo/getServerData',
    server: '2' },
  { baseurl: 'http://localhost:5054/springbootdemo/getServerData',
    server: '2' } ]
```

i want to re arrange it in this form

```
[
  {server:1 , urls: [
    "http://localhost:5051/springbootdemo/getServerData",
    "http://localhost:5052/springbootdemo/getServerData"
  ]},
  {server:2 , urls: [
    "http://localhost:5053/springbootdemo/getServerData",
    "http://localhost:5054/springbootdemo/getServerData"
  ]}`enter code here`
]
```

I want the re arrangement in above format.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! 
Have you tried anything so far? 
StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to 
[try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). 
Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a 
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
For further information, please see 
[how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
and take the 
[tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, that's not JSON - it's an ordinary array. Secondly, you can use `reduce` like so:

```js
const arr = [{baseurl:'http://localhost:5051/springbootdemo/getServerData',server:'1'},{baseurl:'http://localhost:5052/springbootdemo/getServerData',server:'1'},{baseurl:'http://localhost:5053/springbootdemo/getServerData',server:'2'},{baseurl:'http://localhost:5054/springbootdemo/getServerData',server:'2'}];
const res = Object.values(arr.reduce((a, { baseurl, server }) => {
  (a[server] = a[server] || { server: +server, urls: [] }).urls.push(baseurl);
  return a;
}, {}));

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```